# YouTube on Safari Very Stuttery After 11.3

Tags: safari, bug, youtube

I just updated my Mac mini to macOS 11.e3, and it seems as if all of the videos I watch are now very laggy and stutter and I don't know why. Anyone else having this problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but only with audio coming from Safari via headphones. Through builtin speaker it sounds fine. Don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a Safe boot (clear system caches) by holding Shift key at boot and then reboot the Mac.